# python script if argument never met

Tags: python

I have the following python script which every time it runs is updating the database even though the 256sha is the same.

```
import os
import hashlib
import pynuodb

connection = pynuodb.connect("CORE", "priappvmndb01", "ndbadmin", "B1xwmi28", options={'schema': 'markit'})
cursor = connection.cursor()
filename = 'BOND_COMPOSITES_20140624.7z'
thedata = pynuodb.Binary(open(filename, 'rb').read())
with open(filename,"rb") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        m = hashlib.sha256(line)
        sha256 = (m.hexdigest())
sqlget = "select md5hash from raw_data where filename = ?"
sqlins = "insert into raw_data (genericfilename, fileid, fileformat, loaddate, revisionnumber, rawdata, md5hash, filename) values ('bond_composites.csv', 1, 'csv', 'now', 1, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor.execute(sqlget, (filename,))
result = cursor.fetchone()
if sha256 == result:
    print "Nothing to be done."
else:
    cursor.execute(sqlins, (thedata, sha256, filename))
    connection.commit()
    print "Database Updated!"
```

I'm getting from this that the problem lies in my if which means it's probably not recognizing one of the variables?

Comment: what do you see if you put `print type(sha256), type(result)` just above your if?

Comment: aha.  seems result is coming as NoneType.  sha256 shows up as a str.

Comment: correction that was because I truncated the DB.  result shows up as a Tuple.

Comment: I attempted to answer the question, but a) someone else beat me, and b) I made the same mistake you made. Though I should know better, I thought wrapping m.hexdigest() in () would make it a tuple, and it looks like you were thinking the same thing and trying to do that intentionally. While I prefer Tyler's answer below, you could have done sha256 = m.hexdigest(), ( with the trailing , ) to make a tuple out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python DB-API returns a tuple of the row, even if it contains only one value.

```
'foo' != ('foo',)
```

So what you probably want to do is:

```
if sha256 == result[0]:
```